# searching for elements

Tags: document, words

I was assigned homework in which I had to take the given HTML file and create a Javascript file which would search for words within a div class. I have to use both document.getElementById() and .querySelectorAll.

Comment: you can't use document.getElementById to get elements within a class.

Comment: Your code days look for an element that has the `id="searchtext"` and than look for all the children of that element that is `<main>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the elements with: `document.querySelectorAll(".main");`
and then you need to get the search with `document.getElementById("searchtext")`, and then you can add use `addEventListener` to make it run your function when a `click` event occurs:

```js
function Search() 
{
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".main");
    let search = document.getElementById('searchtext').value;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        if(elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(search) > - 1)
        {
            alert('found');
        }
    }

}

document.getElementById('searchbutton').addEventListener('click', Search);
```

```html
    <body>

        <div class="main">

            <p>The Phoenix Suns are a professional basketball team based in Phoenix, Arizona. They are members of the ...</p>

            <p>The Suns have been generally successful since they began play as an expansion team in 1968. In forty years of play they have posted ...</p>

            <p>On January 22, 1968, the NBA awarded expansion franchises to an ownership group from Phoenix and one from Milwaukee. ...</p>

            <ul>
                <li>Richard L. Bloch, investment broker/real estate developer...</li> 
                <li>Karl Eller, outdoor advertising company owner and former...</li>
                <li>Donald Pitt, Tucson-based attorney;</li>
                <li>Don Diamond, Tucson-based real estate investor.</li>
            </ul>

        <p>Page by New Person. <br /> Some (all) information taken from Wikipedia.</p>

        </div>

        <hr />

        <div>

            Search for text:
            <input id="searchtext" type="text"  /> 
            <button id="searchbutton">Search</button>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: thank you, your explanation was very helpful. Do you know how to make the searches non case sensitive?

Comment: what I normally do is: `elements[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the value you are searching for in a variable (`search`). You get this value by calling the property `.value` of an `<input>` tag, which you can select, as you did already by using `document.getElementById("searchtext")`.
Then store the elements you want to search in in another variable, in this case an array by using `document.getElementsByClassName("main")` (notice the getElement**s**ByClassName which indicates it returns a collection).
And you have to call your function somewhere. I just added it to the button `onclick` event in this line:

```
<button id="searchbutton" onclick="search()">Search</button>
```

```js
function search() {
  var search = document.getElementById("searchtext").value;
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("main");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(search) > -1) {
      alert('found');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <p>The Phoenix Suns are a professional basketball team based in Phoenix, Arizona. They are members of the ...</p>

  <p>The Suns have been generally successful since they began play as an expansion team in 1968. In forty years of play they have posted ...</p>

  <p>On January 22, 1968, the NBA awarded expansion franchises to an ownership group from Phoenix and one from Milwaukee. ...</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Richard L. Bloch, investment broker/real estate developer...</li>
    <li>Karl Eller, outdoor advertising company owner and former...</li>
    <li>Donald Pitt, Tucson-based attorney;</li>
    <li>Don Diamond, Tucson-based real estate investor.</li>
  </ul>

  <p>Page by New Person. <br /> Some (all) information taken from Wikipedia.</p>

</div>

<hr />

<div>

  Search for text:
  <input id="searchtext" type="text" />
  <button id="searchbutton" onclick="search()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- get the value of the input field with `document.getElementById("searchtext").value`
- `document.querySelectorAll('.main')` returns a **NodeList** on which you can use the `values()` function that will return an iterator over all the node values in the list
- use then `for(var el of elements.values())` and check for every element if it occurs

## Demo:

```js
function search() {
    var searchText = document.getElementById("searchtext").value,
        elements = document.querySelectorAll('.main');
        
    for(var el of elements.values()) { 
      var idx = el.innerHTML.indexOf(searchText);
      if(idx != -1){
        console.log("Found at: ", idx);
      }
      
    }

}
```

```html
<head>
        <script src = "first.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
        <link href= "dirststyle.css"  type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="main">

            <p>The Phoenix Suns are a professional basketball team based in Phoenix, Arizona. They are members of the ...</p>

            <p>The Suns have been generally successful since they began play as an expansion team in 1968. In forty years of play they have posted ...</p>

            <p>On January 22, 1968, the NBA awarded expansion franchises to an ownership group from Phoenix and one from Milwaukee. ...</p>

            <ul>
                <li>Richard L. Bloch, investment broker/real estate developer...</li> 
                <li>Karl Eller, outdoor advertising company owner and former...</li>
                <li>Donald Pitt, Tucson-based attorney;</li>
                <li>Don Diamond, Tucson-based real estate investor.</li>
            </ul>

        <p>Page by New Person. <br /> Some (all) information taken from Wikipedia.</p>

        </div>

        <hr />

        <div>

            Search for text:
            <input id="searchtext" type="text"  /> 
            <button id="searchbutton" onclick="search()">Search</button>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you should add a onclick function on the button which should be like this `<button id=“searchbutton”, onclick=“Search()”>Search</button>`
And also i don’t think “document.getElementById(“searchtext”).querySelectorAll(“main”);” would work beacuse you should do it in seperate variables like one for search text one for selection. Hope this helps!